Destructuring with default value returns a function
I am destructuring value out of an object like so;
const response = { data: [] }
const { data: { values } = {} } = response

console logging the value of values, its a native function instead of undefined
If I change the response to have an object as the value of the key data, it works as expected
const response = { data: {} }
const { data: { values } = {} } = response


Am as confused as a squirrel in a maze full of mirrors

You're destructuring the values method from an array with data: { values } when data is an array, if you call it something other than values (that doesn't also conflict) then you won't get a native function.

Basically, [].values is a function, and not undefined. In contrast, {}.values is undefined.

Given the following code:
const response = { data: [] }
const { data: { values } = {} } = response

You're attempting to destructure the values property of the data object. Your data object is defined as an array, i.e. { data: [] }
Arrays are objects, and JavaScript will happily destructure them as objects, but since arrays have a values() function defined on their prototype, you're getting that as a result.
